# Can quantum money exist?

Tags: quantum-cryptography

Can a quantum money system exist in which bank (who possesses a secret key $k$) can create quantum states $S$ that anyone (in possession of public key $P$) can verify was issued by the bank without interacting with the bank, but nobody can spend twice?

Comment: @PaulUszak [No](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/171.pdf)

Comment: @EllaRose Well I never.  That's so cunning you could put a tail on it and call it a weasel. But what about the double spend problem? That paper is about simple verification against forgery, and only concerns national central banks. Spending genuine pounds in a sweet shop is entirely unrelated. And how can this money be transferred to the shop as only a central bank can actually create cash via monetary policy decisions. If ever there was  too a broad question... Perhaps the question needs truncation?

Comment: @PaulUszak Double spending is impossible because duplicating the money is impractical, so if I give you some money, then you know I no longer have access to it (because it was physically transferred to you).  Same as with physical cash.

Comment: @Demi Ah. The paper deals with authentication though doesn't it?  It doesn't deal with ownership /transfer /conversion to-from paper. And what would you do with all the notes under my bed? A cashless authoritarian society? And do you realise that quantum thingies don't go down copper wires? And spending on board a plane /ship /submarine /car will be a right PITA. Recall how we all hate QKDNs?

Comment: And if you give (corporate) me your cash, I (as me) don't know one way or another if you gave it me as I work at the other end of the building /hemisphere. Tricky.

Comment: @PaulUszak I know.   This is strictly of theoretical interest until we can store qbits indefinitely at negligible cost.  And the intention is to replace physical cash, not electronic transfers.

Comment: @PaulUszak Imagine a future society that could make an atom-by-atom clone of anything, and could store qbits at negligible cost.   No ordinary physical currency would be secure in such a world, but quantum currency could be.

Comment: @PaulUszak One key goal of such systems is that I can give you money *and nobody whatsoever knows or is involved but you and I*, just like with real-world cash.  No electronic funds transfer scheme I know of has that property.

Comment: @PaulUszak We've been there before … twice. So, I'll just remind you with gentle warning while handling yet another rude/abusive flag with your name attached to it: ***"please, remember to be nice"***. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76870/discussion-on-question-by-demi-can-quantum-money-exist). If you want to discuss this further, please use that chatroom to keep this comment section clean..